# linux + how to ignore (filter) file with space

Tags: linux, shell-script, ls, ksh

Sometimes a file name is created from a couple of names and space between each name as the following:

```
   $ touch  "A B C"
   $ ls
   A B C      <-- one file but has three words !                        
   file1
   file2
   file3
```

How can I ignore (filter) the file that actually created from couple of names as "A B C"?

Expected output

```
     $ ls <filter>
     file1
     file2
     file3
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you do the following:

```
ls | grep -F -v ' '
```

You will not see any file with spaces in the names

( I used to have `fgrep` instead of `grep -F` in the example, but as Hauke Laging pointed out that is [deprecated](http://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html#grep-Programs))

Comment: May I quote my documentation: "Direct invocation as  fgrep is deprecated"

Comment: @HaukeLaging Of course, thanks for pointing out. After 29 years of using `fgrep` I need to change my habits, that will take a bit

Comment: ..though you may see parts of a filename that contains spaces, one or more newline characters, and at least one line not containing spaces. Remember `grep` works on lines and a filename can be made of several lines.

Comment: @HaukeLaging @Anthon: I [sadly] must add that `egrep` is also deprecated and `grep -E` is now the standard.

Answer (score 3):

With GNU ls, i.e. under non-embedded Linux:

```
ls -I '* *'
```

Not that there's much of a reason to skip files whose name contains a space. If you're doing that because you have something like `file_names=$(ls)` or `for f in $(ls)` in a script, [don't parse the output of ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs), and your problem will probably go away.

Answer (score 2):

Using KSH's extended globs, you can filter out filenames in a glob expansion:

```
ls -d -- !(A B C)
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is also helpful:

```
ls -l --quoting-style=literal:
-rw-r--r-- 1 hl hauke 0 28. Apr 16:55 A B C

ls -l --quoting-style=locale:
-rw-r--r-- 1 hl hauke 0 28. Apr 16:55 „A B C“

ls -l --quoting-style=shell:
-rw-r--r-- 1 hl hauke 0 28. Apr 16:55 'A B C'

ls -l --quoting-style=shell-always:
-rw-r--r-- 1 hl hauke 0 28. Apr 16:55 'A B C'

ls -l --quoting-style=c:
-rw-r--r-- 1 hl hauke 0 28. Apr 16:55 "A B C"

ls -l --quoting-style=escape:
-rw-r--r-- 1 hl hauke 0 28. Apr 16:55 A\ B\ C
```